# jQuery style re-application efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question relies partly on knowledge of the inner workings of jQuery.

Say I have a page with vertical overflow that allows the user to scroll down, and the following bit of code in my JS:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (y > 500) {
        $("body").css("background-color", "red");
    }
    else {
        $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine. However, it can be modified like so:

```
var isRed = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (y > 500) {
        if (!isRed) {
             $("body").css("background-color", "red");
             isRed = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (isRed) {
             $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
             isRed = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a reason to choose the second bit of code over the first one? Were I to use the first bit of code, would jQuery apply the style over and over again every time scroll event fired?

I'm used to the way React works, updating only the things that change with every render. Does jQuery include such a feature?

Both bits of code accomplish the same thing. The additional `isRed` condition makes the second version of the code more verbose and complicated, but it might possibly improve efficiency greatly. Does it offer any such benefit?  If so, then it makes sense to use it instead of the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reason to choose the second bit of code over the first one?

Yes, ***if*** you have a performance problem with scrolling. Otherwise, whether it re-applies the style or not, it doesn't matter.

> Were I to use the first bit of code, would jQuery apply the style over and over again every time scroll event fired?

On each scroll event, when you did `$(body).css("background-color", "red")`, jQuery would need to:

1. Create a new object
2. Determine that the string you've passed is a selector, not HTML
3. Check if the selector contains jQuery extensions
4. Query the DOM for the selector
5. Build a one-entry array of the results
6. Loop through that one-entry array effectively doing this:

   ```
   element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   ```

The browser will likely ignore it if the color matches what's already there.

If you want to save jQuery some trouble without making the code more complicated, give it `document.body` to work with so it can skip steps 2-4. You can also simplify the code a fair bit:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    $(document.body).css("background-color", y > 500 ? "red" : "blue");
});
```

Or if you do want to optimize out the call entirely:

```
(function() { // To avoid making `lastColor` a global
    var lastColor;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(document).scrollTop();
        var color = y > 500 ? "red" : "blue";
        if (color !== lastColor) {
            lastColor = color;
            document.body.style.color = color;
        }
    });
})();
```

Note that you can't compare `color` against `document.body.style.color`, they may be (frequently are) in different formats.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Your first one will change the css a few hundred times per second ( if scrolled) , the second is a simple and very efficient debouncer.

May easier:

```
var isRed = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if (isRed !== ( $(document).scrollTop() > 500 )) {
         $("body").css("background-color", isRed?"blue":"red");
         isRed = !isRed;
    }
});
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/hotopoxada/edit?output)